# The id cannot be imported

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How to convert this code in such a way as to get id from channel but also from guild? At the present moment, I am getting the error:

```
    const { id } = msg.channel
        ^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'id' has already been declared
   at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
   at module.exports (C:\Users---------------------\src\handlers                                         
   \event.handler.js:38:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users---------------------\src\index.js:21:1)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Event code:

```
const { Collection, MessageEmbed, Client } = require("discord.js")
const chalk = require("chalk")
const { readdirSync, readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require("fs")
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  name: "channelDelete",

run(msg){
//////////////////////////////////////
const { channel, guild } = msg
const { id } = msg.guild
const { id } = msg.channel
const guildID = id
const client = new Client()
client.settings = new Collection()
///////////////////////////////////////

const log = console.log

// Wczytywanie danych z pliku

fs.readFile(__dirname + `./../config/servers/${guildID}.yaml`, "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
if (err) {
  console.log("The file cannot be loaded:", err)
  return
}

const data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
console.log(data.channelLogID)
if(data.channelLogID === "None"){
  return
} else {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Channel deleted")
  .setDescription(channel.id)
  .setColor(0xcc0000)
  msg.client.channels.cache.get(data.channelLogID).send(embed)
}
})   
}
}
```

I can't do anything about it and every attempt ends with a mistake.
There is maybe another easy way to log a guild?

Comment: You defined the variable `id` twice. These two lines both define the variable: `const { id } = msg.guild`
`const { id } = msg.channel`

Comment: How do I get the id from the guild and channel in one code?

Comment: Just don't destructure them. `const guildId = msg.guild.id` and `const channelId = msg.channel.id`

Comment: It does not work


`TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`